# Loading data from partitioned to non partitioned table

Tags: hive

I want to load a data from Partitioned table to Non partitioned Hive tables.
Is there anyway to load it instead of converting non-partitioned into partitioned table?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: CTAS or insert overwrite-select is good solution in your case. It will run in parallel.

Comment: I have hive external partitioned table and one more table having similar schema but not a partitioned table. Now I want to insert data from partitioned table to non partition table. But when I am writing a query insert into  nonpartition_ table select * from partition_table;  getting error of schema mismatch which is expected but is there any way without creating partition table I can insert data into non partition table

Comment: **(1)** Why don't you select only the relevant columns for the INSERT statement? **(2)** You can simply copy the files from the partition directories to the destination table directory

Comment: 1] I can select only relevant columns but guess if number of partition tables are more than 400 and column count in every table is more than 250 then I don't think so this is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you need partition columns( from partitioned table)  as non-partitions columns into  new table(non-partitioned) ? If yes, then below format will help.

CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE table_name [STORED AS ctas_file_format] [LOCATION 'hdfs_path'] 
AS
select * from partitioned_table

I think you can use hdfs command to move the data to non-partitoned table.